# php upload and parse a file for a chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, csv

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.14.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.14.0/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    <style>
      html, body, #container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  // set the data
    table = anychart.data.table('x');
    table.addData([
{'x': '2015-04-01', 'o': 18.23, 'h': 19.36, 'l': 18.18, 'c': 19.31},
{'x': '2015-04-02', 'o': 19.50, 'h': 19.89, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.29},
{'x': '2015-04-03', 'o': 19.13, 'h': 19.15, 'l': 18.43, 'c': 18.75},
{'x': '2015-04-06', 'o': 18.54, 'h': 18.76, 'l': 18.27, 'c': 18.76},
{'x': '2015-04-07', 'o': 18.76, 'h': 19.14, 'l': 18.63, 'c': 18.76},
{'x': '2015-04-08', 'o': 18.97, 'h': 19.62, 'l': 18.96, 'c': 19.19},
{'x': '2015-04-09', 'o': 19.45, 'h': 19.70, 'l': 19.22, 'c': 19.67},
{'x': '2015-04-13', 'o': 19.69, 'h': 19.85, 'l': 19.37, 'c': 19.59},
{'x': '2015-04-14', 'o': 19.44, 'h': 19.55, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.35},
{'x': '2015-04-15', 'o': 19.21, 'h': 19.25, 'l': 18.51, 'c': 18.83},
{'x': '2015-04-16', 'o': 19.16, 'h': 19.78, 'l': 18.99, 'c': 19.76},
{'x': '2015-04-17', 'o': 19.69, 'h': 19.69, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.20},
{'x': '2015-04-20', 'o': 18.89, 'h': 18.95, 'l': 18.57, 'c': 18.61},
{'x': '2015-04-21', 'o': 18.59, 'h': 19.08, 'l': 18.57, 'c': 18.97},
{'x': '2015-04-22', 'o': 18.76, 'h': 19.19, 'l': 18.70, 'c': 18.78},
{'x': '2015-04-23', 'o': 18.92, 'h': 18.94, 'l': 18.47, 'c': 18.92},
{'x': '2015-04-24', 'o': 19.82, 'h': 21.20, 'l': 19.50, 'c': 20.91},
{'x': '2015-04-27', 'o': 20.55, 'h': 20.82, 'l': 20.28, 'c': 20.40},
{'x': '2015-04-28', 'o': 20.25, 'h': 20.27, 'l': 19.79, 'c': 19.93},
{'x': '2015-04-29', 'o': 20.11, 'h': 20.89, 'l': 20.06, 'c': 20.25},
{'x': '2015-04-30', 'o': 20.60, 'h': 21.10, 'l': 20.01, 'c': 20.26},
{'x': '2015-05-01', 'o': 20.19, 'h': 20.35, 'l': 19.86, 'c': 20.24},
{'x': '2015-05-04', 'o': 20.37, 'h': 20.40, 'l': 19.98, 'c': 20.19},
{'x': '2015-05-05', 'o': 20.14, 'h': 20.24, 'l': 19.64, 'c': 19.79},
{'x': '2015-05-06', 'o': 20.06, 'h': 20.07, 'l': 19.61, 'c': 19.79},
{'x': '2015-05-07', 'o': 19.96, 'h': 19.99, 'l': 19.14, 'c': 19.32},
{'x': '2015-05-08', 'o': 19.46, 'h': 19.64, 'l': 19.14, 'c': 19.42},
{'x': '2015-05-11', 'o': 19.20, 'h': 19.73, 'l': 19.01, 'c': 19.32},
{'x': '2015-05-12', 'o': 19.51, 'h': 20.06, 'l': 19.47, 'c': 19.89},
{'x': '2015-05-13', 'o': 19.92, 'h': 20.00, 'l': 19.67, 'c': 19.75},
{'x': '2015-05-14', 'o': 19.83, 'h': 20.23, 'l': 19.80, 'c': 20.06}
    ]);

    // map the data
    mapping = table.mapAs({'open':"o",'high': "h", 'low':"l", 'close':"c"});
    chart = anychart.stock();

    // set the series
    var series = chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping);
    series.name("ACME Corp. stock prices (apr 2015 - jul 2015)");

    chart.title('Generali');
    chart.container('container');

    chart.draw();
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

php

```
$file = fopen("isp.csv","r");

$lines = array();
while( ($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE ) {
    $lines[] = $row;
}
var_dump($lines);
```

csv file

the csv file is a yahoo finance historical data formatted in

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2016-01-04,2.799631,2.799631,2.703530,2.982000,2.703530,103103922                       
2016-01-05,2.723475,2.756113,2.707156,3.040000,2.756113,70473223                        
2016-01-06,2.745234,2.756113,2.681771,2.958000,2.681771,84184856                        
2016-01-07,2.620121,2.661825,2.560284,2.908000,2.636440,122691238                       
2016-01-08,2.641880,2.692650,2.627374,2.898000,2.627374,96943673                        
2016-01-11,2.618308,2.672704,2.591109,2.858000,2.591109,75364956                        
2016-01-12,2.598362,2.663639,2.585670,2.916000,2.643693,81961998                        
2016-01-13,2.661825,2.734355,2.661825,2.970000,2.692650,96167028
```

I need to sobstitute the table data.addData with the value of the csv file. How i can do that? Someone can provide me a foreach or another cycle to inizialize the value of the table?

Answer (score 1):

ped,

Try the following, since $lines[] is an array

> **Caveat:** the following suggested answer runs with couple of assumptions--
>   1. You will always have 7 data points separated by comma
>   2. AND each data points will not be blank---if you want to, you could avoid this assumption by checking to see if its blank or not by using `isset()`

```
table.addData([
<?php
$isFirst = TRUE;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $lineData = explode(",", $line);

    echo ($isFirst === FALSE) ? "{'Date' : '$lineData[0]', 'Open' : '$lineData[1]', 'High' : '$lineData[2]', 'Low' : '$lineData[3]', 'Close' : '$lineData[4]', 'Adj Close' : '$lineData[5]', 'Volume' : '$lineData[6]'}," : "";

    $isFirst = FALSE;

}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

-Rush

Comment: i tried this code and the explode() method give me this error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prova\prova.php on line 11